# Linear Model with Radial Basis Function Transform - What's wrong?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, inference, linear

## The Maths behind the problem

Suppose I have a training matrix $X$ with $n$ observations and $d$ features
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \ldots & x_{1d}\\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2d} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \ldots & x_{nd}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf{x}}_1^\top \\
{\bf{x}}_2^\top \\
\vdots \\
{\bf{x}}_n^\top
\end{pmatrix}
\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}
$$
Suppose that I want to do a **feature transform** of this data using the Radial Basis Function. To do this, we

- choose $b$ rows of $X$ and we call them **centroids**
  $$
  {\bf{x}}^{(1)}, \ldots, {\bf{x}}^{(b)}
  $$
- calculate using some heuristic a **bandwidth** parameter $\sigma^2$

And then, for every centroid we define a radial basis function as follows
$$
\phi^{(i)}({\bf{x}}):=\exp\left(- \frac{\parallel{\bf{x}} - {\bf{x}}^{(i)}\parallel^2}{\sigma^2}\right) \qquad \forall i\in\{1, \ldots, b\} \quad \text{for } {\bf{x}}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}
$$
We can therefore obtain a transformed data matrix as
$$
\Phi:=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \phi^{(1)}({\bf{x}}_1) & \phi^{(2)}({\bf{x}}_1) & \cdots & \phi^{(b)}({\bf{x}}_1) \\
1 & \phi^{(1)}({\bf{x}}_2) & \phi^{(2)}({\bf{x}}_2) & \cdots & \phi^{(b)}({\bf{x}}_2) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \phi^{(1)}({\bf{x}}_n) & \phi^{(2)}({\bf{x}}_n) & \cdots & \phi^{(b)}({\bf{x}}_n)
\end{pmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times (b+1)}
$$
Then we fit a **regularized** linear model so that **optimal parameters** are given by
$$
{\bf{w}}:=(\Phi^\top\Phi + \lambda I_n)^{-1}\Phi^\top{\bf{y}}
$$

## Implementation

I have implemented this in both R and Python. I put here my Python implementation.

#### Parameters

```
# Set some parameters. Here `reg_coef` is the regularization coefficient
# usually called lambda
n = 1000
d = 2
m = 100
reg_coef = 0.1
b = 2
```

#### Create Training Set

To create the response, I simply feed each row of $X$ into a multivariate normal distribution.

```
# Explanatory variables are uniformly distributed
X = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=(n, d))
# Response is a multivariate normal 
target_normal = multivariate_normal(mean=np.random.normal(size=d), cov=np.eye(d))
y = target_normal.pdf(X)
```

#### Create test data

```
Xhat = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=(n, d))
```

#### Feature Transform

We find $\sigma^2$ with a common heuristic: the median of all the pairwise distances of the data. This step is not important, we could set $\sigma^2$ to pretty much any sensible value.

```
def compute_sigmasq(X): 
    xcross = np.dot(X, X.T)
    xnorms = np.repeat(np.diag(np.dot(X, X.T)).reshape(1, -1), np.size(X, axis=0), axis=0)
    return(np.median(xnorms - 2*xcross + xnorms.T))
# Find sigmasquared for the rbf
sigmasq = compute_sigmasq(X)
```

Define a factory of functions for Radial Basis Functions. Basically, given a centroid ${\bf{x}}^{(i)}$, the function `rbf` returns the function $\phi^{(i)}$ which takes ${\bf{x}}$ as input.

```
def rbf(centroid):
    # define a closure
    def rbfdot(x):
        return(np.exp(-np.sum((x - centroid)**2) / sigmasq))
    return(rbfdot)
```

Create a function to compute $\Phi$ the transformed design matrix.

```
def compute_phiX(X, centroids):
    # Construct phiX
    rbfs = [rbf(centroid) for centroid in centroids]
    list_columns = list(map(lambda f: np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, X), rbfs))
    # Add column on 1s and give correct shape
    list_columns.insert(0, np.repeat(1, np.size(X, axis=0)))
    phiX = np.column_stack(list_columns)
    return(phiX)
```

#### Predictions

Define a function that takes a matrix, say $X$, and the number of centroids that we want $b$. It returns the $b$ centoids chosen at random from the rows of the matrix.

```
def get_centroids(X, n_centroids):
    # Find the indeces
    idx = np.random.randint(np.size(X, axis=0), size=n_centroids)
    # Use indeces to grab rows
    return(X[idx, :])
```

We also define a function that takes in training data $X$, response vector ${\bf{y}}$, regularization coefficient $\lambda$ and the number of centroids $b$. It then does the whole process of

- finding the centroids for the training data
- Computing the matrix $\Phi$ with those new centroids
- Solving the linear system $(\Phi^\top\Phi + \lambda I_n){\bf{w}} = \Phi^\top {\bf{y}}$ for ${\bf{w}}$

and at the end it returns a prediction function that, given some test data matrix $\widehat{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$ of $m$ new observations, it retuns the predictions $\widehat{y}$

```
def make_predictor(X, y, reg_coef, n_centroids):
    # Find centroids
    centroids = get_centroids(X, n_centroids)
    # Obtain transformed data matrix
    phiX = compute_phiX(X, centroids)
    # Find optimal parameters
    w = solve(
        np.dot(phiX.T, phiX) + reg_coef*np.eye(n_centroids+1),
        np.dot(phiX.T, y)
    )
    # construct prediction closure
    def predictor(Xhat):
        # Transform test data features
        test_centroids = get_centroids(Xhat, n_centroids)
        phi_Xhat = compute_phiX(Xhat, test_centroids)
        return(np.dot(phi_Xhat, w))
    return(predictor)
```

To get predictions we then run

```
# Get predictions and actual values
predict = make_predictor(X, y, reg_coef=reg_coef, n_centroids=b)
yhat = predict(Xhat)
yactual = target_normal.pdf(Xhat)
```

Notice that we've also found the actual values `yhat` for the testing set.

## Results

I checked the code many times and it looks correct to me. However, if I then plot the predicted values $\widehat{y}$ against the actual values, it looks *very* weird:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(yactual, yhat)
plt.show()
```

giving

[image: predictions vs real]

What am I doing wrong? It looks like they are normally distributed somehow.

## EDIT1: Simplified code

The following is a slower version of the code above. It presents the same problem during plotting, however, it is much easier to read.

```
def compute_phi(X, centroids, sigmasq):
    # X is the matrix to be transformed. b is the number of centroids
    # gen number of samples
    n = X.shape[0]
    b = centroids.shape[0]
    # now slowly construct the matrix by doing a double loop
    values = []
    for x in X:
        for c in centroids:
            values.append(np.exp(-np.sum((x - c)**2) / sigmasq))
    # now simply reshape it
    phiX = np.reshape(values, (n, b))
    return phiX

def predict(Xhat, X, y, b, reg_coef):
    # find centroids and sigmasq
    centroids = get_centroids(X, b)
    sigmasq = compute_sigmasq(X)
    # transform data matrix
    phiX = compute_phi(X, centroids, sigmasq)
    # Find optimal parameters
    w = solve(        
        np.dot(phiX.T, phiX) + reg_coef*np.eye(phiX.shape[1]),
        np.dot(phiX.T, y))
    # Transform test matrix, need to find test centroids
    test_centroids = get_centroids(Xhat, b)
    phi_Xhat = compute_phi(Xhat, test_centroids, sigmasq)
    # Compute predictions with dot product
    return np.dot(phi_Xhat, w)
```

The problems arise also if we use

```
phi_Xhat = compute_phi(Xhat, centroids, sigmasq)
```

rather than

```
phi_Xhat = compute_phi(Xhat, test_centroids, sigmasq)
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure, you are allowed to change centroids when predicting?

Comment: @Konstantin that is a very valid question. I have no idea, none seems to say it anywhere. I checked Probabilistic Reasoning and Machine Learning by Bishop and also some other resources online, but none specified it.

Comment: None seems to tell me whether I should include a column of $1$s in the matrix $\Phi$ either..

Comment: I am convinced that 1) column of ones is important, and 2) that the centroids are not allowed to shift when you change the inputs (according to the same logic, that makes you keep $w,\sigma$ fixed, they all are parameters of your model, to be determined during training)
Check http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~jebara/4771/tutorials/regression.pdf

Comment: @Konstantin I've tried using the same centroids. Yet, the result is still the same. I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with the way I'm constructing the dataset?

Comment: In compute_phix function, why you have two returns in a row? Also, out of curiosity, why dont use a linear regression package such as glmnet that is perfect for this kind of problems? Also, this line:     rbfs = [rbf(centroid) for centroid in centroids] returns None for me.

Comment: @prony while I was copying and pasting the code here, I made a typo. The return with `rbfdot` should be in the `rbf` function. I'm fixing it now, I'll come back to the other problems in a second

Comment: @prony regarding your second point: I want to try and code it myself to see if I understand it correctly. I've also written an implementation that is much easier to understand and uses for loops, so one can check the mechanisms more clearly. I'm gonna make a new section with the simplified (but slower) version.

Comment: @prony regarding your last point, it returned None because of the typo. If you try now, it should return a list of functions

Comment: I am implementing my version for comparison that I will share in a minute. Can you tell me the MSE on your test data?

Comment: @prony Awesome! For comparison, I'm gonna use `np.random.seed(123)`

Comment: @prony I get `0.0009231416691422496` when I use different centroids for the test data. Instead, if I use the same centroids used for the training data, I get `0.0005380678951527774`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented the problem myself (building on your code) so that you can compare it with your data. I get good results when I use centroids>50. So I think the implementation is correct. I did not use regularization. I simply use the pseudo-inverse function to do regular linear regression

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)


n = 1000
d = 2
m = 100
reg_coef = 0.1
b = 2
n_centroids = 100


# Explanatory variables are uniformly distributed
X = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=(n, d))
# Response is a multivariate normal 
target_normal = multivariate_normal(mean=np.random.normal(size=d), cov=np.eye(d))
y = target_normal.pdf(X)

Xhat = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=(n, d))
yactual = target_normal.pdf(Xhat)

def compute_sigmasq(X): 
    xcross = np.dot(X, X.T)
    xnorms = np.repeat(np.diag(np.dot(X, X.T)).reshape(1, -1), np.size(X, axis=0), axis=0)
    return(np.median(xnorms - 2*xcross + xnorms.T))
# Find sigmasquared for the rbf
sigmasq = compute_sigmasq(X)

def get_centroids(X, n_centroids):
    # Find the indeces
    idx = np.random.randint(np.size(X, axis=0), size=n_centroids)
    # Use indeces to grab rows
    return(X[idx, :])

centroids = get_centroids(X, n_centroids)


## After this line my implementations #####


def cal_distance(x,cent_i):
    ## calculate the distance between the centroid and the other elements
    return(np.sum((x - cent_i)**2))


phi_train = np.ones((n,1))
for i in range(n_centroids):
    cent_i  = centroids[i,:] # get the ith centroid
    dist_i = np.apply_along_axis(cal_distance , 1, X,cent_i) ## distance matrix for i th centroid
    phi_i = np.exp(-dist_i/sigmasq) ## 
    phi_i = np.reshape(phi_i,(n,1)) # dummy rehsape to (n,1)  
    phi_train = np.hstack((phi_train,phi_i)) # horizontally stack the matrix

inv_phi = np.linalg.pinv(phi_train) # get the psudoinverse for regular linear regression

#linear regression coefficiet
coefs = np.matmul(inv_phi,y) ## compute the weights
coefs = np.reshape(coefs,(n_centroids+1,1))  ## dummy reshape

## create phi test
phi_test = np.ones((n,1))
for i in range(n_centroids):
    cent_i  = centroids[i,:] # get the ith centroid
    dist_i = np.apply_along_axis(cal_distance , 1, Xhat,cent_i) ## distance matrix for i th centroid
    phi_i = np.exp(-dist_i/sigmasq)
    phi_i = np.reshape(phi_i,(n,1)) # dummy rehsape 
    phi_test = np.hstack((phi_test,phi_i))


y_predict = np.matmul(phi_test,coefs)

plt.plot(yactual,y_predict,'*')
plt.xlabel('actual')
plt.ylabel('predicted')
plt.title('n_centroid = ' +  str(n_centroids))
```

[image]
[image][image]

This is how the first 10 rows of phi_train look like for n_centroid = 2:
[image]

## Comment

It does not make sense to use different centroids for test data. It is analogous to only use the statistics from training data (e.g., mean, std) while normalizing the data. In theory, you don't have any access to the test data (unseen data). So you are not supposed to make any computation on it (e.g, computing centroids in our case or computing mean for data normalization).

Comment: I haven't accepted it yet cause I'm still working to understand what went wrong in mine. Even if I set regularization to `0`, I still get weird shapes for `100` centroids. Going line by line, I managed to show that we both get the same `phi_train`, so that's good. Somehow though, our coefficients are different: I think it has to do with the pseudoinverse, but not sure why this happens

Comment: I've created the following manual psuedoinverse function 

```def manual_pinv(x):
    pinv = np.matmul(
        np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(x.T, x)), 
        x.T)
    return pinv```

Comment: This function seems to work for small arrays. For instance, if we create an array `some=np.array([[1, 3, 7], [5,1, 2], [4,4,5]])` and we run `np.linalg.pinv(some)` we get `array([[-0.05172414,  0.22413793, -0.01724138],
       [-0.29310345, -0.39655172,  0.56896552],
       [ 0.27586207,  0.13793103, -0.24137931]])` and similarly, we get the same if we run `manual_pinv(some)`

Comment: However, if we calculate the pseudo inverse of the `phi_train` matrix, we get two very different results

Comment: This is a very interesting point. I would also assume that pseudo-inverse equals to $inv(X^TX) X^T$. It turns out, as stated here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html), the psudo-inverse function (pinv) uses SVD and automatically cuts off for small singular values which consequently regularizes the regression. For example, when I replaced pinv function with $inv(X^TX) X^T$, I still got similar results for n_centroid<50 (slightly worse). However, I got very bad results for n_centroid ~= 100. Because it overfit which was handled automatically by the pinv.